# fasthttp некоррктно работает

Tags: golang

Пытаюсь использовать fasthttp с шаблонизатором amber, но в браузере получаю пустую страницу

есть такой обработчик

```
type DTS struct{}
func handler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    compiler := amber.New()
    compiler.ParseFile("./templates/index.amber")
    tpl, _ := compiler.Compile()
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(ctx, "index.html", DTS{})
}
```

либо вместо

```
tpl.ExecuteTemplate(ctx, "index.html", DTS{})
```

пробую использовать, но ничего не дает

```
tpl.Execute(ctx, "index.html")
```

А при обычно пакете net/http все работает, как надо

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    compiler := amber.New()
    compiler.ParseFile("./templates/index.amber")
    tpl, _ := compiler.Compile()
    tpl.Execute(w, "index.html")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему указав тип контента

```
ctx.SetContentType("text/html")
```